# questions regarding the design of std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some questions regarding the design of `std::initializer_list`.
I didn't find answers in **[support.initlist]**.

Why does it have an explicitly defined default constructor?

Why this constructor is not `constexpr`?

Why the method `size()` is not `constexpr`?

Why there's no traits giving the size of `initializer_list` (like specializing `std::tuple_size`)?

Why it's not possible to statically access its elements (like specializing `std::get`)?

What happens when `sizeof` is applied to `initializer_list`?

Comment: Why did I just imagine my 8-year old son machine-gunning me with questions about the sky being blue, where chocolate milk comes from, what gravity is...

Comment: @JohnDibling:  Does your 8-year old son have a Stack Overflow account?  No, you say?  Are you sure?

Comment: I think the reason for most of these things is that std::initializer_list isn't actually a container. It doesn't have value semantics, it has pointer semantics. It's only use is, at it name implies, to initialize objects. I think it was designed to be a lighter template than things like vector or tuple.

Comment: @JohnDibling Your metaphor is accurate:) I'm like the rooky asking the gods of c++ why they choose do so

Comment: @thb:  Questions about minecraft and yu gi oh are off-topic at stack overflow, so I doubt it. :)

Comment: "Why it's not possible to statically access its elements (like specializing `std::get`)?" because `std::initializer_list` can be passed between compilation units without encoding its length in its type, unlike `std::tuple`.  So the same reason as why we don't have `std::get` specialized for `std::vector` or any other random-access iterator or container: All existing uses `std::get` varies its return type depending on its input template argument integer.

Comment: @Yakk - you're right: unlike std::array the size is not encoded in the type but assignments to initializer_list are fixed size and I don't see why the compiler cannot keep track of that size? (even if the object is passed to another compilation unit)

Comment: You want `std::initializer_list<T>` users and constructors to be basically implicit templates on `std::initializer_list<T, N>`, and constructor or function to be instantiated "remotely" depending on which `N` are used. That isn't easy for compilers to implement, and C++11 was designed to be easy for compilers to implement. Or, in short, the same reason why you cannot forward declare a `template` in a header, fully implement it in a `.cpp` file with no explicit instantiations, and in a completely different compilation unit instantiate it: nothing fundamental, it is just hard.

Comment: @Yakk excellent example. your comments seem to answer all the questions not just "Why it's not possible to statically access its elements (like specializing std::get)?"

Comment: Nope: `constexpr` objects do not have those same issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From section 18.9 of the C++ Standard:

> An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of
>   objects of type const E. [ Note: A pair of pointers or a pointer plus
>   a length would be obvious representations for initializer_list.
>   initializer_list is used to implement initializer lists as specified
>   in 8.5.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying
>   elements. — end note ]

I think the reason for most of these things is that std::initializer_list isn't actually a container. It doesn't have value semantics, it has pointer semantics. Which is made obvious by the last portion of the quote: *Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.* Seeing as they were intended solely for the purpose of initializing things, I don't think it's that surprising that you don't get all the niceties of more *robust* containers such as tuples.